# Executing compound Firestore query in Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am writing a few triggers who work on a firestore databse of movies and users.
in this trigger' I am trying to display a new user the top rated movies in a list of genres he chose. for that I have an array of his favourite genres, and I want to query the database inside a foreach loop:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import { __values } from "tslib";
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'; 


admin.initializeApp();
const films = admin.firestore().collection("Films");

export const new_user_recommend = functions.firestore
    .document('/Users/{email}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
        const new_user = snap.data();
        if(new_user){
            const new_email = new_user.email;
            const favourite_genres = new_user.favourite_genres;
            let film_id_arr: string[] = new Array();

            favourite_genres.forEach((genre: string) => {
                films.where('genres', 'array-contains', genre).orderBy('avg_rating', 'desc').limit(5).get()
                .then((list_book: any)=>{
                    list_book.forEach((element: any) => {
                        const film_element = JSON.parse(element.data());
                        film_id_arr.push(film_element.data().id);           
                    });
                    return film_id_arr;
                })
                .catch((error: any)=>{
                    console.log(error);
                    console.log("Error loading films");
                });                
            });
        } 
        return 0;            
    });
```

the problem is I always get the error message in the catch clause (so for each genre in the array I get the error message). I double checked to make sure the strings in the array are the same as the strings who might be written in 'genres' field for each film document.
This lead me to believe my query is somehow incorrect. Is that the case?

I edit to add some important details. the exact error I get is "Could not load the default credentials", So would that indicate a problem with user authentication rather than the query itself?

Comment: What is the `error` object telling you?  You should log it.  Also bear in mind that you will probably need better handling of promises in this code, if you are running it in Cloud Functions.  Also I'm not sure how this is considered a "compound" query.  What you have right now is the sane number of queries as you have genres.

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by logging it? I see the error message I wrote in the console.log() command ("error loading films"). Also what is problematic with my promise handling here? this is intentionally not the full code of the function, since I wanted to keep it simple, so I might already be doing what you think I should be

Comment: Your catch function is being delivered an `error` argument.  This will tell you more about what's wrong.  This is standard JavaScript error handling.

Comment: OK. Sorry for being a hassle, I am new to this. I logged the error object and it gave me "Could not load the default credentials"

Comment: That sounds like information you should put into the question itself, including the entire function code that you deployed.  Please edit the question to explain what's going wrong.

Comment: The question was edited. Thank you for being patient

Comment: I'm sure that is not all the code.  Where do you import firebase-functions and initialize the Admin SDK?  Please show everything: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: BTW if you resolve this error, the function will almost certainly still not work the way you expect because of the way you're ignoring promises.

Comment: I added my imports and the intializeApp() command. My intentions were to try and give the minimal amount of code that is relevant to the issue as I perceived it, so I apologize again for the inconvenience. If you have a better suggestion to handle this promise I will be glad to see it, If I'm doing it wrong it's because I gathered everything I know from a range of different examples and tried filling the gaps myself, as I said I am new to this and I find the documentation a bit confusing. I appreciate every bit of help

Comment: I suggest doing a web search for the error message "Could not load the default credentials" since this does happen in some circumstances in Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quick search it seems that your problem is that you're using firebase-admin without providing valid credentials [website](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).

Atleast that's how it seems judging from the error code.

The credentials for deployed functions are necessary only for firebase-admin but not for firebase-functions.

Comment: Also the error appears as a list because you make the query for films in a ForEach method